# Heroku RoR app not working after adding activeadmin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, activeadmin

My RoR app was working fine on heroku until I added the activeadmin gem, and now when I push it to heroku, I get a page like this:

```
Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

The heroku logs command only gives me...

```
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: [NOTE]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: Bug reports are welcome.
2012-04-14T21:25:32+00:00 app[web.1]: For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
2012-04-14T21:25:33+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 139
2012-04-14T21:25:33+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

I'm not sure where to go from here.  Does anyone have any idea how to get my local app (working perfectly) to work on heroku?

thanks,
brad

Comment: have you run the migrations in Heroku?

Comment: Yes, I ran that and this is what I get back: `Running rake db:migrate attached to terminal... up, run.1`

Comment: That error is Ruby blowing up - I would raise a support ticket.

Comment: OK, thanks.  Just made a support submission.

Comment: Hi, i have the same problem. I have set a bounty of 50 points. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845417/active-admin-gem-rails-3-2-3-heroku-error-logs

Answer (score 0):

I am doing a blindly guess here, but when you install the Active Admin you need to run the migrations after pushing to Heroku.

Try doing this:

```
heroku rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Yes, I rank that and got `Running rake db:migrate attached to terminal... up, run.1` back.  No errors or anything.

Comment: This is not deprecated. Terminal now says to run 'heroku run rake'