# Active Admin Gem - Rails 3.2.3, Heroku Error logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, activeadmin

I am having problems understanding the error logs. I am using Active Admin, all works well on my local server but when i push to Heroku i can not login or use active admin. I am a little stuck as to what the problems is. The front end of my wife works but when i try to login for the first time i get this error.

I have run

```
 heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Application.rb

```
   config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

routes.rb

```
 break if ARGV.join.include? 'assets:precompile'
```

**Heroku logs**

```
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:153:in `respond'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:146:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:239:in `respond_with'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.1.0/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:9:in `new'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436:in `_run__2148348972389484395__process_action__581573497384646045__callbacks'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/rai
lties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:40:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.3/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.3/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.3/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.1.18/lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:54:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.1.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.1.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.1.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dragonfly-0.9.12/lib/dragonfly/cookie_monster.rb:9:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:467:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2527400173333692808__call__757062616006589650__callbacks'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dragonfly-0.9.12/lib/dragonfly/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `block in pre_process'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `catch'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `pre_process'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:38:in `receive_data'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:61:in `start'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   script/rails:6:in `require'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-3020d04d5c8f/app/views/active_admin/devise/shared/_links.erb (1.1ms)
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-3020d04d5c8f/app/views/active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/active_admin_logged_out (292.9ms)
2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 456ms
```

**Config/env/development.rb**

```
 # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true
```

**Gem File**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development do
        gem 'pg'
        #gem 'sqlite3'
end
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'chosen-rails'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "activeadmin", :git => "git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git"
gem "zurb-foundation"
gem "friendly_id", "~> 4.0.1"
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'rack-cache', :require => 'rack/cache'
gem 'dragonfly', '~>0.9.12'
gem "fog"
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'tinymce-rails'
```

**Update:**

I on my gemfile i am now using

```
ruby '1.9.3'
gem  'rails', '3.2.5'
```

but the error log has

```
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
```

Is heroku not supposed to choose Ruby 1.9.3 for me?

Comment: Look on the server log, it probably has something to tell you, why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this two things:

```
config/environments/production.rb config.assets.compile = true
```

in your gem file

```
gem "activeadmin", :git => "git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git"
```

and `bundle install`

push to heroku and see it works

Comment: This is how my application looks like. And the problem is, i can't figure what the problem is from the error message above.

Comment: Tried this but still not working on remote. I can log on to admin page. but all the other pages including home page are not working.

Answer (score 2):

Move `gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'` and `gem 'pg'` out of the assets group, bundle and try it again.
I would do a mandatory `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`
and add the `public/assets` updates to my commit.

If ever you want to rebuild your assets, just `rm -rf public/assets`
and run the asset precompile command again.

You can `git rm public/assets --cached -r`
and
`git add public/assets`

Do a commit and push to heroku.

Comment: I have tried this. I also deleted the app and created a new one. The migration went well. DeviseCreateAdminUsers: migrating....... But i still see the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing that you haven't run your migrations since the **pg gem** is tucked away in your assets group. You'd likely have gotten an error upon issuing `heroku run rake db:migrate` if you tried to run them under these conditions.

Also, I would advise putting your thin gem in production or global environment. Make sure you have a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile), otherwise heroku will use webrick.

Comment: I moved the pg gem and the thin gem into a production group. I did run the migrations.  Would you know what this is referring to: 2012-06-01T06:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML

Answer (score 0):

Need to add this to `production.rb`

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( active_admin.css active_admin.js active_admin/print.css)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got very similar error messages when I forgot to run $ heroku run rake db:migrate.  I created a new Family model and set the root of the app to a family#show page in development.  I got the same cryptic error message that you got when I deployed to Heroku and was able to solve it by running the migrations in the production database and creating a Family object in the console.